# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined node.js passing json array into method

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm new with working with JSON (and coding in general) and I'm stuck for a couple of hours on what seems to me like a simple problem. I'm trying to pass an array from one method to the next but get the following errormessage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Via the logs I can see that the variable is set when return by methodA but is undefined when used in methodB.

Here are my code samples:

```
function getRecipes(ingredients) {
  ....
    } else {
      var output = [];
      recipes = JSON.parse(body);
      recipelist = recipes.recipes;
      //console.log("Recipes: " + recipes);
      //console.log("Recipeslist: " + recipelist);
      for (i=0; i<recipelist.length; i++) {
        test = recipelist[i];
        //console.log(test);
        output.push(test);
      }
      console.log("output");
      console.log(output);
      return output;
    }
  });
}

function buildGenericMessage(recipes) {
  var elements = [];
  console.log("Recipes");
  console.log(recipes);
  for (i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++) {
    //....
  }
```

The code is executed by:

```
sendGenericMessage(sender, buildGenericMessage(getRecipes(getIngredients(text))));
```

This is the console log of the variable output:

```
[ { publisher: 'My Baking Addiction', 
    f2f_url: 'http://food2fork.com/view/035865', 
    title: 'The Best Chocolate Cake', 
    source_url: 'http://www.mybakingaddiction.com/the-best-chocolate-cake-recipe/', 
    recipe_id: '035865', 
    image_url: 'http://static.food2fork.com/BlackMagicCakeSlice1of18c68.jpg', 
    social_rank: 100, 
    publisher_url: 'http://www.mybakingaddiction.com' },
  { publisher: 'My Baking Addiction', 
    f2f_url: 'http://food2fork.com/view/e7fdb2', 
    ...},
..]
```

And this is the console log for the recipes variable:

```
Recipes: 
undefined
```

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I will guess that `getRecipes` is asynchrone. Or the `else { ... }` block is never reached. It seems to me that you left out the most important part of `getRecipes`.

Comment: On which line does it error?

Comment: @2426021684 This line `for (i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++) {`

Comment: I would concur with @andlrc, please post the full code for these functions. Also, if it's asynchronous, there may be callbacks involved, which would require changing how the `sendGenericMessage` line is structured.

Comment: I can see a tell-tale `});` in `getRecipes`.  You've been bitten by a callback.  Congrats!  It happens to every single JS programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `getRecipes` has a callback in it (I can tell by the `});`).  Read up on them here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks) or any other source you can find.  It usually takes 2 or 3 articles to get a good feel for it.

Basically your `recipes` object is being populated after some asynchronous task, but the function is return far before then.  The way to get the data you need is something like:

```
function getRecipes(ing, cb) {
  // stuff
  asyncFun(ing, cb)
};

getRecipes(ing, function(err, recipes) {
  buildGenericMessage(recipes);
});
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for your quick replies! I got it running and understand now asynchronous js (a bit)!